# Output positive and negative number in a random array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have to create a program that separates the positive and the negative numbers 
from a random array.
I tried to create void to separate only the positive numbers at first (`visualizzaVettorePos`) but I keep getting the `Id return 1 exit status`.
Any thoughts?

**Code :**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIM 100
#define NUM 20

void caricaVettore(int*, int);
void visualizzaVettore(int*, int);
void visualizzaVettorePos(int[], int[], int);

int main(){
    int mioVettore[DIM];
    int vettorePos[DIM];
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    caricaVettore(mioVettore, DIM);
    visualizzaVettore(mioVettore, DIM);
    visualizzaVettorePos(mioVettore, vettorePos, DIM);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void caricaVettore(int* vettore, int quanti){
    int i;
    printf("Inizio fase caricamento (input)\n");
    for(i=1; i<=quanti; i++){
        vettore[i]=rand()%(NUM*2+1)+(-NUM);
    }
    printf("Fine fase caricamento (input)\n");
}

void visualizzaVettore(int* vettore, int quanti){
    int i;
    printf("Inizio fase visualizzazione (output)\n");
    for(i=1; i<=quanti; i++){
        printf("Valore indice %d: %d\n", i, vettore[i]);
    }
    printf("Fine fase visualizzazione (output)\n");
}

void visualizzaVettoriPos(int vettore[], int vettorepos[], int quanti){
    int i,j;
    j=1;
    for(i=0; i<quanti; i++ && j++){
        if (vettore[i]>=0){
            vettorepos[j]=vettore[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: Vettori and Vettore are not the same thing

Comment: _"I keep getting the Id return 1 exit status."_ is not an error message. You probably get a real error before that. What is it? What line/column does it direct you to?

Comment: I made a mistake, now i changed the code but it doesn't output the positive numbers

Comment: so you probably need to submit a new question, with the latest code, and a clear statement of the problem, neither of which are in evidence here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behaviour. In C array indexes start at 0 and not at 1.

Therefore you need to change your `for` loops like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < quanti; i++)
```

instead of:

```
for (i = 1; i <= quanti; i++)
```

And for the same reason in the `visualizzaVettoriPos` function

```
j = 1;
```

should be

```
j = 0;
```